# Persistent disk size is not changing - Google Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, diskspace, persistent-storage

I changed size of my persistent disk from 10GB to 20GB.

Screenshot[image: Screenshot of persistent disk image in Google Compute Engine]

Now when I run df command in my server, I can still see only 10GB space.

`user@edudrona-prod-vm:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       10186040 6755924   2889652  71% /
udev               10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs            1535964    8528   1527436   1% /run
tmpfs            3839908       0   3839908   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            3839908       0   3839908   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             767984       0    767984   0% /run/user/1003`

I am just running simple Wordpress site using Bitnami. Except from changing 10GB to 20GB, I did not make any change to increase disk space. Do I have to play around with settings anywhere else as well?

Update:
I got following output from resize2fs command:

`user@edudrona-prod-vm:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
The filesystem is already 2620416 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks).

`resize2fs` alone is not sufficient because what it does is resizing to fill the extents of the carrier partition, but your /dev/sda1 is still the old size.  You need to resize that first.  On some operating systems the whole root partition upsizing is done automatically on boot, so try rebooting to see if just that does the trick.  Otherwise, you'll need to follow the manual steps.  Be careful and make sure to back things up first.